# CoreData : Saving states makes getting data very laggy

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm gonna give as much code as possible so I can explain whats happening. but a brief overview is this. A user presses a button that pulls a large list(UITableView). About 30,000 entries. It grabs this from Core Data. and it takes no time at all.

However in this UITableView each item can be "selected" and it changes the state inside Core Data. IF and only IF the user selects an item, the list takes 400%-1000% longer to pull up after it has been dismissed and reaccessed. AND no matter how many times you pull it up and dismiss it AFTER a cell has been 'selected' it always takes as long.

Additionally, if the user never touches anything. it opens and dismisses very quickly, infinite number of times.

ok so code time.

Basic fetch request when the view loads. Limit batch to 20 entries.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:self.entityName];
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;
    NSSortDescriptor *serverSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortid" ascending:YES];

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[serverSort];
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = YES;

    searchFilter = [[NSString alloc] init];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[(id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:self.entityName];
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
}
```

This is where the problem is created. Saving the selected states for the cells. after the user selects any item, (runs this code) its gonna lag. No matter what they do.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSFetchedResultsController *resultsController = [self fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:tableView];
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [resultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([[managedObject valueForKey:@"selected"] isEqual:@YES]) {
        [managedObject setValue:@NO forKey:@"selected"];
    } else {
        [managedObject setValue:@YES forKey:@"selected"];
    }
}
```

Anyone have any thoughts or similar problems. It's very confusing, because it comes up so quickly until they interact with the list.

Love to hear some advice, even if its just directional, or something i should explore more.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you run instruments on it to see what core data is doing?

Comment: Why don't you save the current selected object and when the user selects another cell, set the current selected object to NO, set the object in the selected cell to YES, then you only need to refresh 2 rows?

Comment: @wain - I have not, but I will do that now.

Comment: @dthien is that not what it is currently doing?

Comment: @Wain I'm pretty new to instruments, do you think the timeprofiler is the place to start or should i begin with a different one?

Comment: Did you tried to save the context after set the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instruments supplies several different Core Data specific tools that you can use to analyse the situation:

- Core Data Fetches
  Records invocations of executeFetchRequest:error:, providing information about the entity against which the request was made, the number of objects returned, and the time taken for the fetch.
- Core Data Saves
  Records invocations of save: and the time taken to do the save.
- Core Data Faults
  Records information about object and relationship fault firing. For object faults, records the object being faulted; for relationship faults, records the source object and the relationship being fired. In both cases, records the time taken to fire the fault.
- Core Data Cache Misses
  Traces fault behavior that specifically results in filesystem activity—indicating that a fault was fired for which no data was available—and records the time taken to retrieve the data.

Based on your description you should start with fetches and misses, then faults and see what turns up.

There are also some good WWDC videos on this topic.